# Grafico com mesma cor de linhas para fatores

Tags: r, ggplot2

Tenho um data frame (DF) de consumo por animal e por dia
Segue abaixo os dados abaixo de somente dois animais

```css
Animal  Dia Consumo
5       9   2533.96
5       10  2329.06
5       11  2943.79
5       12  3361.62
5       13  2890.82
5       14  2538.98
5       15  2978.81
5       16  3038.76
5       17  3038.76
6       10  2314.82
6       11  2434.75
6       12  2643.99
6       13  2320.58
6       14  2439.56
6       15  2139.6
6       16  2459.54
6       17  2339.59
```

Quer plotar um grafico do consumo em funcao do dia. Mas quero que para cada animal a linha seja da mesma cor (cinza). Estou usando o comando abaixo, mas o grafico gera cores diferentes para cada animal. Tambem nao quero que sai a legenda.

```
DF$Animal <- factor(DF$Animal)
ggplot(data = DF, aes(x = Dia, y = Consumo, colour= Animal)) +
  geom_line()+theme(legend.position="none")+ scale_size_identity() +
  theme_bw() +
  xlim(c(0, 90)) + 
  ylim(c(0, 3000))
```

Comment: Tire `colour` de `aes` e use `geom_line(colour = "grey")`. Nota: não é necessário transformar `DF$Animal <- factor(DF$Animal)`, o `ggplot` trata disso se for possível. (E neste caso é possível.)

Answer (score 3):

Você precisa especificar cada `Animal` no `group`, e especificar `color` no `geom_line`:

```
a <- read.csv2("dados.csv")
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = a, aes(x = Dia, y = Consumo, group = Animal)) +
  geom_line(color = "grey") +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = unique(a$Dia))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Os diferentes tons de cinza podem ser encontrados [aqui](http://sape.inf.usi.ch/quick-reference/ggplot2/colour)